# Changing page URL and connect newsletter to MailChip

Tags: plugins, menus, pages, slug, newsletter

I have a page on WordPress (example: `abc.wpengine.com/abc`) and I want to change it to `abc.wpengine.com/xyz`.

I tried to fix the page inside **Pages** and **Posts**, but it was not there. I also went into my theme's *Custom Options* > *Customizing* > *Menus* which is where I found the menu item and the page (`abc`) and "*Custom Link*" as the label:

[image]

I went ahead and changed the menu URL to `abc.wpengine.com/xyz`, but when I try to access the page it says:

> The page isn't redirecting properly

As a novice to WordPress, I don't know where to reflect this change in order to make the page accessible to the new URL.

On the same website, I have a newsletter opt-in with one field (*Email ID*) in the sidebar:

[image]

I want to have the email that the user signs up with sent to [MailChimp](http://mailchimp.com/). What's the best way to connect to my MailChimp account? Do I need to add an embed code or a plugin?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Changing the url in your menu won't change the name or the url of the page you want to modify.  In your menu, you set the **link** to where your page is, you don't **define** it there.  The error you have is because you have too any redirects.  To give you an answer, it would help to know what your setup is currently. I notice you have _staging_ in your domain name so I assume you are trying to move from a staging environment to a production one. So my guess is that you haven't defined properly your site url in your production environment.  Please give more details so we can help you.

Comment: @bynicolas Thanks for your answer... I have a staging website working and I want to change a Page URL to a new URL. Later I will deploy it to the Live website. So, all I did was changed that from Menu (which from your comment I understand is wrong). I tried to find the page under pages and posts so that I can change the Permalink but it was not there. Also, I saw a few tutorials (https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL) but they all deal with Home Page so I don't know how to change it. Also, could you help me with MailChimp integration! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm not sure I get all the picture here.  But my guess is that you don't see your post content in _Pages_ or _Posts_ because it might be a custom post type.  Could it be that you have some custom post type on the left side bar of your admin panel?

Comment: @bynicolas In Admin I saw a Plugin called "Magic Fields' and my page name under heading Label (Menu name). I do not see any menu called "custom post type" appreciate your help. Regarding Popup I found that it's a Widget for Newsletter Signup!

Comment: you wont see _custom post type_ because a custom post type is a wp customization that uses the same frame as WP posts, but customized for whatever purpose. sorry for not being clear on that one.  You must have some place where you define the content of the page you are trying to change the link for, don't you?

Comment: @bynicolas "You must have some place where you define the content of the page you are trying to change the link for, don't you?" Could you please elaborate that!

Comment: @bynicolas How I can chat with you? or send direct messages!

Comment: you do not have enough reputation to chat on SE, but I'll try to give you permission here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/44171/char-over-question-236341

Comment: @bynicolas May bad! That didn't worked! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see you in the chat room and tried to give you write access... did it work ? -- edit: actually it failed!

Comment: To elaborate on my previous comment.  How do you update the content of the page you are trying to change the link for. in your image in your question I see _".staging.wpengine.com/pharmad"_ where/how do you update that _pharmad_ page?

Comment: @bynicolas Thanks for your help... Appreciate that and respect your knowledge. The links were hardcoded into a Plugin. And for MailChimp, I used WP Text Widget.

Comment: Glad I could provide some assistance. If your links were hardcoded into the files, then I believe that's the only way you can edit/update them (or if filters were provided by the author then that would also be a possible way to change those values). Let us know if you need more help :)

Comment: @bynicolas Can you help me with this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256031/image-crop-resize-function-code-sinppet-plugin-to-adjust-crop-images-during-uplo PLEASE... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Changing the page URL

If the page you are talking about (ex: ABC) is on your WordPress site, it will automatically be listed in a dropdown called **Pages** in the *Menu*, like so:

[image]

From there you can check the page you want and click "**Add to Menu**".

When you add a "*Custom Link*" to the menu, this is mainly used if you are linking external websites that is not on your WordPress website.

To change the URL slug of your page (`/abc` to `/xyz`), under the *Pages* section in your Dashboard, open up the page in question (ABC in this case) to edit it. When you have the page opened in your editor, at the top, you should see the following:

[image]

Where you see `http://abc.wpengine.com/abc/` click "**Edit**" next to it. This will allow you to set the new URL slug to `xyz`.

#### 2. MailChimp

Looking at your screenshot, I'm guessing that you are already implementing a newsletter plugin?

To have your subscriber's information added to your MailChimp mailing lists, I'd look into using the following plugin: [MailChimp for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/)

There's more details on how to use this plugin on the link that I gave you.

Comment: You are not answering the question... It specifically said that she don't see her "page" there because it's not a core WP Page

Comment: @Ethan Jinks O'Sullivan, thanks for your answer! But, I can't see a way to get Permalink for the page so that I can edit it. I will check MailChimp Plugin. I found that it's a WordPress Widget on The Website for Newsletter Opt-in!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the permalink for the page that you are changing isn't from your website? It will help if you could elaborate more

Comment: @Ethan, thanks for your help. I was able to fix it... The links were hardcoded into a Plugin. And for MailChimp, I used WP Text Widget.

Comment: @Sheryl Glad to help. Be sure to click the checkmark next to my answer to indicate that your question has been resolved.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Absolutely!