# Image Crop/Resize Function/Code Sinppet/Plugin to adjust/crop images during upload

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-recommendation

We have a Directory website http://prntscr.com/e76vrf running at LISTABLE Theme.

1. Currently, when a User Signs Up and Upload the "Profile Photo", "Cover Photos" there is no provision to adjust the Photo and the wider photos cut off after saving them. So we want to add an image resizer/cropper which can let users to resize or crop the image. I tried to find a plugin this but I was not able to settle on any. Do you know of a code snippet/function or may be a plugin which can do this? Let me know how to integrate the code if it's a code solution.
2. Also, How I can dynamically fetch and show the total numbers of listings on the home page http://prntscr.com/e76u5i

Please advise with the most efficient solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-= 1 =-**

This is untested and might not work with your theme if it's using a custom function to upload the actual images, but I would add the size you want using [`add_image_size( 'profile_photo', $width, $height, array( 'center', 'middle' ) );`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) to your `functions.php` file.

Then you can retrieve the image using [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) passing as the `size` argument, your custom size name `profile_photo` created with `add_image_size()`.

As a side note, the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` filter only works in the admin area. So keep that in mind.

Also, I'm thinking that your theme might already be using `add_image_size` for profile images, it might already be declared in your `functions.php` file. Check it out as you might be able to adjust the size there already.

**-= 2 =-**

For your second question, again this is dependant on your setup but I would suggest you check out the [`found_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties) property of the `WP_Query` object.

So you can build a query that looks for all your listings and echoes the `found_posts`property for that query object, similar to

```
$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'listings', // assuming your listing have their own post type
  'post_per_page' => -1,

);


$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// Then print where you want
echo $my_query->found_posts;
```

of course you can modify your query to filter your posts by other arguments suiting your needs.  Check out the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for all available arguments and properties.

Comment: Thanks @bynicolas... I will give it a try. You are always helpful and decent :) PS. I have started reading your blogs on https://www.bynicolas.com/ (waiting for new post). Also, I like the UI and UX of you your website https://www.bynicolas.com/. I believe you have coded a custom theme for it... Is that right?

Comment: @Sheryl Thanks for the kind words and for following my blog... I have a ton of articles waiting to be published (I just need to find time to finalize formatting!) Anyhow, you are correct, it's a custom theme based on the genesis framework. I'm glad you like it :) take care

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [wp_handle_upload_prefilter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_handle_upload_prefilter) for performing  actions on images *right* after they're uploaded but *before* they are actually saved. 

You could perform various actions on the file such as image resizing. 

Use

 `if ( false !== strpos ( $file['type'], 'image' ) )`

to determine if the uploaded file is an image. 

`$file['tmp_name']` will point to the actual file *before* it's saved, i.e. The file's temporary name, this is the file you need to perform actions on.

Comment: thanks @kabiir ! However in which file should I write this code?

Comment: This isn't something you can write in any file. It explains how you could achieve image resize during the upload process. If you want a complete solution you might want to check out WordPress plugin repository or CodeCanyon for premium plugins such as this one [User Pro](https://codecanyon.net/item/userpro-user-profiles-with-social-login/5958681?ref=kabiir)

Comment: On StackExchange sites, you should ask one question per post and if you need Custom Customizations to your site you should hire someone rather than editing WordPress files yourself. This question is specific to a theme `LISTABLE` you should contact the developer for appropriate advice. The developer will be more familiar with your current settings and can give you most efficient advice.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this!

Comment: Reading back my response to your follow up, I now feel I was not very helpful (in a way that I would've appreciated if I was in your place). I apologize for the behaviour.

Comment: That's fine... Sometimes we humans act in a manner which we aren't!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correct.

Here is a solution on how to resize the image on upload, so users wont be able to upload images larger than 1920x1920. This way you can instruct your users to always upload the largest image, and the website will do the rest for you to save disk space.

```php
// Hook the function to the upload handler
// https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload/
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'resize_image_after_upload');

function resize_image_after_upload($image_data){
  // Set to null to disable that width/height resizing
  $max_width  = 1920;
  $max_height = 1920;

  // Check if there is a valid file
  if(empty($image_data['file']) || empty($image_data['type'])) {
    return $image_data;
  }

  // NOTE: We are not resizing any gifs, to avoid resizing animated gifs
  //      (which I think is the most common gif nowadays)
  $valid_types = array('image/png','image/jpeg','image/jpg', 'image/webp');
  if(!in_array($image_data['type'], $valid_types)) {
    return $image_data;
  }

  // Get image image_editor
  // https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_image_editor/
  $image_editor = wp_get_image_editor($image_data['file']);
  if(is_wp_error($image_editor)) {
    return $image_data;
  }

  // Check if the image editor supports the image type
  if(!$image_editor->supports_mime_type($image_data['type'])) {
    return $image_data;
  }

  // Perform resizing
  $sizes = $image_editor->get_size();
  if((isset($sizes['width']) && $sizes['width'] > $max_width)
    || (isset($sizes['height']) && $sizes['height'] > $max_height)) {
    // Resize, but do not crop
    $image_editor->resize($max_width, $max_height, false);

    // We will use the default recommended image quality
    // Change, if you want to set a custom quality
    //$image_editor->set_quality(90);

    $image_editor->save($image_data['file']);
  }

  return $image_data;
}
```

Hope this helps! If I ever update this snippet, you can also find it [on my blog](https://blog.nicohood.de/wordpress-resize-image-after-upload). There is also a [plugin](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/resize-image-after-upload/) for this, but I personally like a small snippet more.